# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (46:43), When using web 3 react for wallet connection in react dapp

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, metamask, web3-react

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tfJO.png)

> ./node_modules/@metamask/utils/node_modules/superstruct/dist/index.mjs 46:43
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (46:43)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> var path = failure.path;
> |     var msg = path.length === 0 ? message : "At path: >".concat(path.join('.'), " -- ").concat(message);
>
> > ```
> > _this = _super.call(this, explanation ?? msg);
> > ```
>
> |     if (explanation != null) _this.cause = msg;
> |     Object.assign(_assertThisInitialized(_this), rest);

**When I deleted node modules and reinstalled it, the website showed up for a few seconds and then this error**

Using this reference to connect wallet in react application: https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/web3-react

Also I am using lower version of react scripts ("react-scripts": "^2.1.3") because it also caused some other issues when implementing wallet connection

I want to integrate wallet connection so user can interact with smart contracts using website, I have done this in many of my previous projects but recently I am encountering many issues with web3 or some packages

Comment: please share your error message as the plain text format